# Can I use reactstarterkit.com for building client side react app not served from node.js?

Tags: reactjs

As I can tell react starter kit (reactstarterkit.com) is intended to be served from node.js and developed further into full stack JavaScript app. Can I use it only for developing pure client side react app?

Comment: I guess I will have to edit build npm script and transform html component into static html page?

Comment: Or use entirely different starter kit? Like https://github.com/koistya/react-static-boilerplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you would need to modify the build process to make it generate static `.html` pages similar to how it's implemented in [react-static-boilerplate](https://github.com/koistya/react-static-boilerplate) by the same author.

You may want to keep all existing build scripts in case you need to switch back to a full-stack Node.js/React app, but just add a support of building only static portion of the site by appending `--static` flag to the build command (`npm run build -- --static` or `npm start -- --static`). With this flag there will be an additional build step which traverses all the routes and generates static `.html` pages, or if you don't care about SEO it can generate a single `index.html` page in the root of the build output folder and make your static site serve this page for all HTTP requests.